# C++: no value is printing when passing array for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, c++17

I'm new to C++ programming. Whenever I run this, it doesn't print anything.

What I want is to ask the user for their names infinite times and only break after typing "quit". And after typing "quit" it must print all the items in the array. But it's not printing anything. Where am I wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int count = 0;
std::string arr[] = {};

void my_funct()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string names;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your name: \n";
        getline(std::cin, names);
        if (names == "quit")
        {
            my_funct();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string arr[] = {names};
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: `std::string arr[] = {names};` where is this being used? An entirely useless statement. Did you want to instead use a vector here? : `std::vector<std::string> arr; arr.push_back(name);`

Comment: `std::string arr[] = {names};` is also a local variable that goes out of scope at the first `}` right after `count++;`

Comment: FYI the else is redundant since you break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr` in `my_funct()` and `arr` in *if-else* statement are two different arrays. You are declaring local version in *if-else*, which after each iteration of loop is destroyed. You also declared it as an array of zero length - meaning it cannot hold any elements. What you want in your case is `std::vector` (you even included appropriate header).

You can then resign from `count` variable and use `vec.size()` (I've renamed `arr` to `vec`) instead.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> vec;

void my_funct()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << vec[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter your name: \n";
        getline(std::cin, name);
        if (name == "quit") {
            my_funct();
            break;
        }
        else {
            vec.push_bash(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Roxanne, accept either this or the other answer. Both are correct

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int count = 0;
vector<string> arr;

void my_funct()
{
    for (auto ar : arr) {
        std::cout << ar << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string names;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your name: \n";
        getline(std::cin, names);
        if (names == "quit")
        {
            my_funct();
            break;
        }
        arr.push_back(names);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is your code I tried to correct. If you need  do not understand or need explanation just ask and I'll try to explain

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int counet = 0;

vector<string> arr;

void my_funct()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    
    std::string names;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your name: \n";
        getline(std::cin, names);
        
        if (names == "quit")
        {
            my_funct();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            arr.push_back(names);
        }
    }
}
```